# Is it possible to apply CSS only to tags with onClick parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few different types of tags that have the `onClick` parameter. Is there any way I could apply CSS only to the tags that have this `onClick` parameter?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/30m9c1ov/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
div[onClick] {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="alert('123')">One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div onClick="console.log('123')">Three</div>
<div>Four</div>
```

This pretty much does what it says on the tin, it will match an element with the given attribute.

You could make this narrower if you want to match a specific function using something like `[onClick^=functionName]` (This example will select anything that starts with "functionName", including "functionName2"), but leaving it as `[onClick]` will match any element with an `onClick` attribute, regardless of the attributes content.